# Multiple adsense publisher id's mixing and matching etc

Tags: adsense, ads

Does anyone know the adsense TOS regarding using more than one publisher ID
on a site.

can a page have 1 ad using publisher ID#1 and another ad using publisher ID#2
    i.e the top banner ad is using one pubid and the bottom banner ad is using another
    pubid

This is important as I have been noticing some very strange results lately, but
I want to make certain what I am doing is 'legal' before saying more..

Comment: Ok it seems I can http://adsense.blogspot.com.au/2008/07/sharing-your-ad-space.html

Comment: **Something is wrong** , on my sites front page, I keep a pageview counter which determines which publisher ID I use.. Two publisher ID's share the front page, alternating for each pageview... our partner and I compared our adsense earnings the last few days, and the page views reported by google are correct, close to 50/50 , however my partners cpc is almost 10x higher than ours... Why would this be the case ???? the ads are exactly the same format for both of us, we're both from the same country and the content on the page is static....

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to have multiple Adsence id's on the same site, even the same page as long as the total number of adds per page is not exceeded (I don't think extra adds will show up if you have more than 3 anyway.)

There are a number of sites around that allow you to include your Adsence ads with your content. Take a look at these:

1. [www.weebly.com](http://www.weebly.com)
2. [www.hubpages.com](http://www.hubpages.com)
3. [www.triond.com](http://www.triond.com)
4. [More...](http://www.webnots.com/adsense-revenue-sharing-sites.html)

> Its 100% allowed to use more than one publisher ID on a single page or across a website provided the total number of ad units per page is not exceeded (that per page not per account.)

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/eBwPjDixtUY

> The answer is that yes, we do allow this. But before you place your ad code on the same page or site as another publisher, here are a few important points to keep in mind:
>
> - The maximum number of products per page will remain the same.
> - If you don't own the site, you'll need to receive permission from the site owner to display your ads on their pages.
> - We're unable to divide earnings between accounts, so any revenue generated will be credited to the account associated with the ad unit that was clicked or viewed.
>     Any shared site that displays Google ads must also comply with our program policies.
> - You're responsible for the content of any page where your ad code appears. Before placing your ad code on another publisher's site, we recommend reviewing the site for any policy violations.
>
> And one final tip before giving your code to another publisher -- try using our Allowed Sites feature to monitor where your ads are appearing and keep your account in good standing.

http://adsense.blogspot.com/2008/07/sharing-your-ad-space.html